# Modify Class Constant in Python

Tags: python, class, class-constants

In Python, I define a class:

```
class X():
    _CON = 0

    def __init__(self, var):
        self.y = var*self._CON
```

Is it possible to change the constant `_CON` for an instance of `X`? For example, I attempt to do the following

```
X._CON = 3
x = X(2)
a = x.y
```

I expect `_CON` to be changed from 0 to 3 and thus `self.y = var*_CON = 2*3 = 6`. What is the right way to do this short of creating a new class?

---

**Edit**:

I have found the answer. My second code works. However, it changes not `_CON` of the instance `x` of the class `X` but that of the class `X` itself. The following code changes `_CON` of the instance `x` not that of the class `X`.

```
x = X(2)
x._CON = 3
x.__init__(2)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? What is your expected outcome? What do you expect the value of `a` to be?

Comment: If I execute your example as is I get an exception `NameError: global name '_CON' is not defined`. You will either need to change it to `self.y = var * X._CON` or `self.y = var * self._CON` as [@Mateen Ulhaq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365102/mateen-ulhaq) states below.

Comment: IMHO if you improve your question with a [minimum complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you will get better answers

Comment: @MarkMikofski: I have edited my question. Is it better clearer now?

Comment: yes it is clearer, but your example code does not even run. Have you tried it? The answer to your question is yes, but you will have to change your code example as indicated in my comments and the upvoted answers below

Comment: @MarkMikofski: I have corrected the code just you suggested. The code now runs. Assigning value to X._CON direct just like my code works.

Comment: Can the downvoters explain their reasons for downvoting? Aside from needing to change _CON to self._CON in __init__, the spirit of the question is quite clear. What is there not to like the question?

Answer (score 1):

`_CON` is a class level variable, not an instance level variable.  If you change `_CON` in your class then the value of `_CON` will change for all instances of your class X.  If the value of `_CON` will not be static then I'd include it as an instance level variable instead of defining it as a class variable.

Comment: I agree but see my code correction and edition to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is. When you assign to an instance attribute you mask the class attribute.

So if you do `C()._CON` you are referring the instance namespace while if you do `C._CON` you are referring the class namespace. You can assign to instance and class attribute is not touched.

```
c = C()
c._CON = random()
```

You can reach class namespace from instance by `self.__class__._CON`  or `type(self)._CON`

Nothing of this was tested.

Pay attention that `_CON` is not globally defined at `X.__init__` so you should be getting an `NameError: global name _CON is not defined` error at `x = X(2)` line.

And there is another problem, since you use `_CON` in `__init__`, changing it after instantiating it will have no effect on the `y` attribute because this value was already computed. In this case the better thing to do is to extend the `X` class and customize the `_CON` attribute.

```
class Y(X):
    _CON = 3
y = Y(2)
```

Comment: I tested my code, with the slight correction _CON -> self._CON. It works as I intended. Also please see my new edit in the question.

Comment: Calling __init__ explicitly is not very elegant... But yeah it may work. Why not extending?

Comment: I agree with the inelegance of calling __init__ explicitly. I probably should have used a class method name other than __init__. I just wanted to change the class constant which is used in the class method. Extending class is a good idea too.

Comment: But OP specifically says not to create a new class. A way to this so that it updates every time `X._CON` is changed would be to make `y` a [property](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) and set `var` to an instance variable, then `y = property(lambda self: X._CON * self.var)` means you can change `X._CON` even after you instantiate `x = X(2)`. Sorry for bad use of lambda, but comments don't multi-line snippets.

Comment: @MarkMikofski is exactly right about my prohibition of creating a new class. Property is new to me. Good to know that.

Comment: what about putting `_CON` as a parameter of `__init__` with a default value of 3? The you can change at instantiation time `x = X(2,CON=2)`!?

Answer (score 1):

As I said in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704491/modify-class-constant-in-python/45704708#comment78410449_45704708), which I will expand on here, if OP wants to be able to change `X._CON` on the fly, even after instantiating `x = X(var)` and without writing a new class then one way might be to make `y` a [property](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) and `var` an instance attribute like this:

```
class X(object):
    _CON = 0

    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.var * X._CON
```

then ...

```
>>> x = X(2)
>>> x.y  # returns 0

>>> X._CON = 3
>>> x.y  # returns 6
```

*N.B.*: As others have indicated and I think the OP has already discovered, this example uses the class attribute `X._CON` and changes to a class attribute will affect all instances of that class. For example, executing the following after instantiating `x = X(var)` from above, the value of `X._CON` will still be 3; it will not be 0.

Please pay very careful attention to the difference between capital `X` the *class* and little `x` the *instance* in the examples below:

```
>>> x._CON = 23  # <-- doesn't affect x.y b/c x.y = x.var * X._CON
>>> x.y  # still returns 6 b/c X._CON = 3 still

>>> x10 = X(10)
>>> x10.y  # returns 30 b/c X._CON = 3

>>> x._CON  # returns 23
>>> x10._CON  # returns 3 since we changed X._CON to 3
>>> X._CON  # returns 3 <-- this is the **class** attribute
```

Therefore if you want the value of `_CON` to be particular to each instance then use `self._CON` instead of `X._CON`. Starting afresh ...

```
class X(object):
    _CON = 0

    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.var * self._CON  # <-- use **instance** attribute
```

then ...

```
>>> x = X(2)
>>> x.y  # returns 0

>>> x._CON = 3  # <-- use **instance** attribute
>>> x.y  # returns 6

>>> x10 = X(10)
>>> x10.y  # returns 0 b/c x10._CON = X._CON = 0

>>> x10._CON = 7  # <-- use **instance** attribute
>>> x10.y  # returns 70

>>> x._CON  # returns 3
>>> x10._CON  # returns 7
>>> X._CON  # returns 0
```

There are a few more variations, like what happens to the instance attributes `x._CON` and `x10._CON` in the 2nd example using `self._CON` if you change the class attribute `X._CON` either before or after setting the instance attributes `x._CON` or `x10._CON`. I'll leave those examples for the reader to explore.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get change the constant _CON for an instance of X.

Nope. If you want this, you must use an instance variable like `self.con`.

In your example, `_CON` is attached to the class `X`. To attach it to an instance, you *must* use `self`.

Comment: OP could also use the *class* name itself, by that I mean, instead of `self._CON` he could use `X._CON`. If I change OP's example to `self.y = var * X._CON` then I get `a = 6`

Answer (score -1):

No, from a instance/object you can't update a class variable. Because it's by design, has to be constant for all the object. Though some tricks exists(create a class method to update the variable or as usual go with **init** method.)..

```
class MyClass:
    _CON = 1

    @classmethod
    def update(cls, value):
        cls._CON += value

    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
        self.update(value)

a = MyClass(1)
print (MyClass._CON) #o/p: 2
```

And you must think 10 times before you you update anything that starts with a underscore(somebody is saying don't touch it...)